# Drag and drop a folder of 55 GB inside a document library inside SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, administration, limitations, drag-and-drop

I have a large folder containing images, videos and documents of size 55 GB and it contain 7 main folders. now i drag and drop the large main folder inside SharePoint online document library and the drag and drop is uploading the files till now without any issue (3 hours from now).. so is there any problem of drag and drop this large folder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a migration tool rather than drag and drop. Microsoft offers the free [Migration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepointmigration/mm-get-started) that's simple to use for scenarios like this.

The reason being is that if you use the drag and drop method, you'll be throttled and/or it won't complete successfully. Using a migration tool like MM will first send it at full speed into an Azure blob storage account and then SPO will ingest it from there (which can still be slow, but at least you don't have to wait for it on your PC).

Comment: but if anything went wrong i should get an error .. currently the upload is working fine it have been running for 3 hours now

Comment: You'd get an error, yes. But that is a significant amount of data and you're likely going to be throttled.